# How to parse syslog (rfc 3164) timestamps using std::chrono::parse?

Tags: c++, timestamp, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm trying to parse [syslog timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164#section-4.1.2) that start with an abbreviated month name using [chrono::parse()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse), but can't seem to get it to work (using MSVC 2022 community edition, with latest updates).

The following example runs 2 simple "tests", each writing a timestamp in a specific format, and then parsing the result using equivalent format specifiers to get the same time point back. The first test succeeds, the second one (syslog timestamp format) fails:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <format>

void test
(
    std::string const& out_fmt,
    std::string const& in_fmt,
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds> const& tp
)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << std::vformat(out_fmt, std::make_format_args(tp));
    std::cout << "Tstamp: " << out.str() << "\n";

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds> tpp;
    std::istringstream in(out.str());
    if (!(in >> std::chrono::parse(in_fmt, tpp)))
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing failed!\n";
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Parsed: " << std::vformat(out_fmt, std::make_format_args(tpp)) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds>
        tp{std::chrono::seconds{1683656751ull}};

    std::cout << "Test 1\n";
    test("{0:%F}T{0:%T}Z", "%FT%TZ", tp);

    std::cout << "Test 2\n";
    test("{0:%b} {0:%e} {0:%T}", "%b %e %T", tp);

    return 0;
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
Test 1
Tstamp: 2023-05-09T18:25:51Z
Parsed: 2023-05-09T18:25:51Z
Test 2
Tstamp: May  9 18:25:51
Parsing failed!
```

Any suggestions on how to get test 2 working as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've lost the year when formatting so you can't parse it back to a specific time point.

You can parse it manually into something like `struct { std::chrono::month_day date; std::chrono::hh_mm_ss<std::chrono::seconds> time; }`. Be careful attaching a year, especially if it happens to be February 29th.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. When adding the year to Test 2 (`test("{0:%b} {0:%e} {0:%Y} {0:%T}", "%b %e %Y %T", tp);`), it works just fine.